# connecting django app with python script in my LAN

Tags: python, django

I have a local script that collects info about the tasks of the printers in my LAN, and I also have a Django app that holds general info about my work. The thing I want to know is how to put the info generated for the local script in the django database that is hosted in pythonanywhere?.

I use python 2.7 and django 1.8.4 with registration-redux package.

Any help will be useful?

Thanks

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you could create a POST API in your django app that is consumed by your local scripts that sends data to your remote DB. The related views will process incoming data and save them as needed.

Comment: I think his question is how to connect from outside his LAN 
`hosted in pythonanywhere?` @Newtt